# Can primitive recursive functions be simulated in the smallest reasonable primitive recursive group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, computability-theory, computer-science

**Second Edition**, completely rewritten with unchanged questions.

The said questions are motivated by the bizarre wording of the concluding § in *A Class of
Reversible Primitive Recursive Functions* by L. Paolini, M. Piccolo & L. Roversi (Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science **322** (2016) 227–242, doi:[10.1016/j.entcs.2016.03.016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2016.03.016), [author pdf](http://www.di.unito.it/%7Epaolini/papers/2015reversiblePrimitiveRecursive.pdf)).
Kudos to the 2 upvoters for making sense of the 1st Ed.: 2 days after posting it, I couldn't & came up with this. Apologies and  thanks to the 100+ viewers for your efforts & special thanks to Andrej Bauer for your sharp questioning.

The paper itself is not problematic. It purports to simulate the usual set of [primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) (PRF) by means of carefully chosen bijections from $\mathbb{Z}_∗$, the free monoid over the signed integers, to itself. Then, they proceed the other way around, to simulate those bijections using PRF's; which, it turns out, amounts to simulate all the members of the group they generate.

I attempt here to make sense of their concluding remark by rephrasing it in group-theoretic terms. Sorry if it is old moons to you, and any comments to that effect are welcome: all this is way beyond the fields I know. 
So, I shall explain my terminology at some tedious length, before I can restate the results of the Paolini-Piccolo-Roversi paper and only then, ask my questions. Meaning you might find the post more entertaining by reading it from the bottom up; you're welcome to try.

---

The *locus dramatis* is the group $U_p$ of bijective functions from $\mathbb{Z}^p$ to itself, with group law the composition of functions and unit the identity $I_p$; and the disjoint union thereof $U_*=\bigsqcup_{p \in N} U_p$.

In my ignorance of established terminology, I chose the following; again, your comments are welcome if you know any better.

- Identifying tuples from $\mathbb{Z}^p$ with words from the free monoid $\mathbb{Z}_*$, we let $|w|$ denote the size of the tuple $w$ & $(w_1, w_2)$ denote $w_1$ **concatenated** with, i. e. followed by, $w_2$, and identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}^1$;
- a denizen of $U_p$ has **arity at most $q$** if, up to conjugation by some reordering of its $p$ arguments, it is equal to the Cartesian product $f_q \times I_{p-q}$ for some $f_q \in U_q$;
- lifting **concatenation** to an operation over $U_*$, we rewrite $f_q \times I_{p-q}$ as $(f_q, I_{p-q})$ and extend every bijection $ f \in U^p$ to a bijection $ (f, I_\infty) : \mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[X]$.
- This switch, from the free monoid $\mathbb{Z}_*$ to polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, disposes of technicalities about how to feed a function with a word too short for its taste: just **zero-pad** it the way you pad a polynomial with null terms to match degree requirements;
- this promotes  $U_*$ to the status of a group acting on $\mathbb{Z}[X]$: the **group of** (bijections of) **fixed arity** with values in $\mathbb{Z}$;
- From now on, the subscript $q$ in $f_q \in U_p$ will systematically denote the **arity** of $f$: the smallest $q$ such that $f$ has arity at most $q$. By exception, all the $I_q$'s remain available for tuple juggling, as aliases of the identity function: $I_0$, the unit element of $U_*$ and the only one of arity $0$.

So much for the preliminaries! Finally,

- groups acting on $\mathbb{Z}_*$ have a unique feature: an **exponentiation** defined over the whole group. As usual, $f^k$ in $U_p$ denotes $f$ composed $k$ times with itself for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ : $f^0 = I_0$, $f^{-z} = (f^{-1})^z$.  Then, the **exponentiated** $f_q$ is the bijection $f_q^* : (z, w_q) \to (z, f_q^z(w_q))$ for all $(z, w_q) \in \mathbb{Z}^1 \times \mathbb{Z}^q$; it has arity $q+1$.
- With $U_*$ closed under exponentiation, a **minimally recursive group** is any subgroup of $U_*$ that is closed under exponentiation and under permutations of (finite subsets of)  function arguments; and,
- for any subset $S$ of $U_*$, the **primitive recursive group generated by** $S$, denoted $R_*(S)$, is the smallest subgroup of $U_*$ containing $S$ that is minimally recursive. $R_p(S)$ is $R_*(S) \cap U_p$.

**Beware, gentle reader!!!** My choice of terms is far from ideal. It suggests $R_*(S)$ is the natural representative of the usual PRF's in reversible computing; however, it is only true if the set of generators is neither too small, nor too rich. More on this in a moment.

---

In the above setting, the primitive recursive group chosen by Paolini–Piccolo–Roversi has 4 generators: the unit *translation* I denote $++ : \mathbb{Z}^1 \to \mathbb{Z}^1$; a *zero-testing* bijection: $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ that maps $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$ and $(z, 0)$ to itself, $z \ne 0$; a *pairing* bijection $\mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$  that maps  $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \{0\}$, bijectively, to $\mathbb{Z}^1 \times \{0\}^2$; an *unpairing* bijection that provides the inverse mapping, $\mathbb{Z}^1 \times \{0\}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \times \{0\}$. 
That this $R_*(S)$ contains simulations of all the PRF's and conversely, can be simulated by PRF's, is not in question; I take it for granted.

The bizarre conclusion is, they regard an "open issue" whether the pairing function is "independent from the remaining functions" *(sic)*; said functions being, I *surmise*, the other generators of their group. 
At first glance, the issue seems to me closed and tightly barred with a negative answer: there *are* PRF's that map bijectively $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and it looks like an easy programming exercice to extend one to a pairing fucntion in $R_*(S)$, as soon as it features a zero-testing bijection. 
In other words: if $S$ is restricted to the fist 2 generators, $R_*(S)$ still contains the other 2; it just makes it all the easier to simulate $R_*(S)$ with PRF's.

In view of this, let me suggest a tougher issue: what if we also remove the zero-testing capability? In other, hopefully unambiguous, words:

> **Q1:** if $S$ contains only translations over $\mathbb{Z}^1$, does the resulting group,
> $R_*(\{++\})$, contain a **zero-testing bijection** ? Such
> a function is any bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^p$ to itself that maps $(z, 0, 0_{p-2})$ to some $(z, b, w_{p-2}(z))$, with $b=1$ if $z=0$, else $0$.

As soon as one such bijection is found, it is a straightforward matter to build a cleaner one upon it, one of arity $p+1$ that maps $(z, 0, 0_{p-1})$ to $(z, b, 0_{p-1})$.

Given that concatenation & exponentiation behave well with respect to the Euclidean norm over $\mathbb{Z}^p$ and that, for $S$ as above, $R_p(S)$ contains the linear group over $\mathbb{Z}^p$, the next question cries out to be asked:

> **Q2:** if $S$ is the orthogonal group over $\mathbb{Z}^{p-1}$, does $R_p(S)$ contain a **zero-testing isometry**? This one is a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^p$ to itself, tweaked to
> preserve Euclidean norms: it maps $(z, 1, 0, a_{p-3})$, for *some*
> constant $a_{p-3}$ and *any* $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, to $(0, 1, 0, w_{p-3}(0))$ if
> $z=0$, else to $(z, 0, 1, w_{p-3}(z))$; with $w_{p-3}$ of size $p-3$, having the same
> norm as $a_{p-3}$ and otherwise unspecified.

The answer to **Q1** is likely negative, which turns the group over 1 generator $R_*(\{++\})$ into a fairly exotic fellow: the smallest group with reasonable claims to be closed under some sort of recursion, yet too small to simulate the PRF"s.
It offers addition and iteration, hence a sizeable bit of linear algebra, even of polynomial algebra with substitution... only equality testing is wanting. Hence the title of this post, and my choice of the term "minimally recursive" .

I added **Q2** out of curiosity and a personal distaste for undecidable questions: if my life depended on it, I would bet the answer to Q1 is "no or maybe undecidable" and the answer to Q2 "decidably no".

Comment: Can you please write down explicitl what $w_{p-2}$ is in the first question, without resorting to "*ad lib*"?

Comment: Please don't say "unspecified" or "arbitrary". Give *one particular choice*, and then say later that the choice did not matter. I am immediately suspicious about "arbitrary". How arbnitrary? Can I make it a non-bijection? Perhap I can start choosing things so that I sneak in some non-computability somewhere? I should not be worrying about these things before I understand the definitions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, how about something non-problematic? How would one represent addition in this setting? I am not asking these question to answer your question, but to *understand* your question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Addition is w/o zero testing: by way of what I called "signed recursion".   Shall we move to chat? Thanks for your patience anyway.

Comment: Thank you for *your* patience. Yes, let's move to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112602/discussion-between-francois-jurain-and-andrej-bauer).

Comment: @YCor thanks for tidying up. I doubt very much $\mathbb{U}$ is standard for such a peculiar group, so I'll change back only that one.

Comment: @FrançoisJurain sure I just coined it, just using mathbb to distinguish from a certained fixed explicit group vs $G$ which is varying. Of course choice is yours and $U$ is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Why, shiver mey timbers! Q1 has a **positive** answer. I cannot believe I am the 1st to notice it, although I do not recall even hearing of it, as a classroom exercise or otherwise; if you know it in published form, kindly provide a link & I will be glad to credit the inventor.

So, we are looking for an algorithm that compares the integer $z$ with zero, using *only* incrementation and exponentiation. First, note those are enough to square integers, which reduces the problem to comparing the *un*signed $z^2$ with $0$.

The key observation is, they are also enough to compute the quotient and remainder of the division of $n \ge 0$ by $2$: defining $Add_{1/2} : (n, b, c) \to (n+b, c, b)$, the exponential ${Add_{1/2}}^*$ maps $(2 \cdot n+b, 0, 0, 1)$ to $(2 \cdot n+b, n, b, 1-b)$.

Then, replace $2 \cdot n + b$ with $n$ and reiterate at least $\log_2 (n + 1)$ times, adding the successive remainders. This computes $L_2(n_0)$, the sum of the digits in the base 2 expansion of $n_0$, in ${} \le n_0$ iterations: $L_2(\sum_{k \ge 0} {b_k \cdot 2^k}) :=  \sum_{k \ge 0} b_k$. The function $L_2(n_0)$ only takes on the value 0 when $n_0 = 0$, otherwise it is ${} \ge 1$: almost the one we were looking for.

(**Edited §**, found a simplification). So, define the sequence $n_{k+1} := L_2(n_k)$; from any $n_0 \ge 1$ it falls in a few steps to $1$, where it remains stationary. This is because $L_2$ is strictly decreasing when $n_k \ge 2$. Whereas it is 0 whenever $k \ge n_0 = 0$.

*Et voilà,* your zero-testing function: $n_{n_0 + 1}$. It is a not-so-easy exercise, then, to make the computation reversible; however it is pure programming, not math.
(**Edited** on second thoughts); not so pure. The usual *programming* trick to reversibly replace $2 \cdot n + b$ with $n$ by means of a pairing function is not available yet, and we must do with an *arithmetic* ersatz; it may help answer Q2 to expose it.

So: we have bijections $ Swap: (m, n) \to (n, m)$, $ Add(z): (n) \to (n + z)$ and $Halve(2 \cdot n  + b): (z, 0, 1) \to (z+n, b, 1-b)$; we work with a 9-tuple $((2 \cdot n + b)_0, 0_1, 0_2, 1_3, l2_4, c_5, 0_6, 0_7, 1_8)$ where $c$ acts as a bit bucket, or rather a bit dump to throw used binary digits after reclaiming their component in the tuple. 
Now, compose the following in sequence:

- compute quotient & remainder: $Halve((2 \cdot n  + b)_0): (0_1, 0_2, 1_3) \to (n_1, b_2, (1-b)_3)$;
- add the remainder: $Add(b_2): (l2_4) \to ((l2+b)_4)$;
- reclaim component 0: $Add^{-2}(n_1): ((2 \cdot n + b)_0) \to (b_0)$; $Add^{-1}(b_2): (b_0) \to (0_0)$;
- lay $b$ on top of the dumped bits: $Add^2(c_5): (0_6) \to ((2 \cdot c)_6)$; $Halve^{-1}((2 \cdot c)_6): (c_5, 0_7, 1_8) \to (0_5, 0_7, 1_8)$; $Add(b_2): ((2 \cdot c)_6) \to ((2 \cdot c +  b)_6)$;
- reclaim components 2 and 3: $Swap^{(2 \cdot c + b)_6}: (b_2, (1-b)_3) \to (0_2, 1_3)$.

The final tuple is $(0_0, n_1, 0_2, 1_3, (l2+b)_4, 0_5, (2 \cdot c + b)_6, 0_7, 1_8)$: swap components 0-1 and 5-6, and you are ready to iterate. In the end, component 4 will have grown from $0$ to $L_2(2 \cdot n + b)$ and component 0 dwindled from $(2 \cdot n + b)$ to $0$, swap them and you are ready to go for $n_{k+2}$.

I do not claim authorship for separating fixed from changing function arguments and for the notation $value_{index}$ and in  the preceding §§: they are so natural, I probably reinvented the wheel as is my wont. Again, just provide a link to published material & I will gladly credit the inventor.

This leave **Q2** open, although without computability-theoretical added value. Still, if you care to provide an answer, I will rather accept it than this one.

Comment: @Andrej-Bauer Thanks; LaTeX is not my kink, really.

Comment: Very nice! Who would have thought. So this is now enough to get all p.r. functions, yes?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I feel confident I can get them; let's move to chat if you want to discuss it. Hardly any chance I'll find a way to remove the last generator as well, though.